# How to get an element from li value and manipulate its value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently don't know how to get the value of the class like the code i'm posting below. If i click the li class that has value of 0 i want it to do A If i click the li class that has value of 1 i want it to do B

```
I'm using bootstrap and jquery/javascript.
Sorry if my code seems not tidy, this is my first post , i'll try to tidy it up in the next posts. 


I've been doing inspect elements and it's showed me no error, but the variable X isn't getting it's value from li.
```

Here it is i wanted it to do A if the selected is value 0

```js
$(".clDropdown").click(function() {
    debugger ;var x = document.getElementsByClassName("clDropdown").selectedIndex;
    if (x == 0) {
        alert("DO A");
        debugger ;
    } else if (x == 1) {
        alert("DO B");
        debugger ;
    }
});
```

```html
 <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        More <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">//if 0 do A
        <li class="clDropdown" value="0"><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
        <li class="clDropdown" value="1"><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
I expect that if i click the li that value 0 it'll do A , and if i click the li that has value 1 it'll do B
```

Comment: [selectedIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) is for `<select>` elements not `<li>` elements. Also see [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to get `index` you can use `$(this).index()`
- I prefer to use `data` attribute and get data with `$(this).data('value')`

```js
$(".clDropdown").click(function() {
  debugger;
  var x = $(this).data('value');
  if (x == 0) {
    alert("DO A");
    debugger;
  } else if (x == 1) {
    alert("DO B");
    debugger;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    More <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">//if 0 do A
    <li class="clDropdown" data-value="0"><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
    <li class="clDropdown" data-value="1"><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome @PiPio .. Please don't forget to accept the answer.. Have a nice day :-)

Comment: Ahh okay sorry still new to this :D